# How to append an output that I just got from "awk" command after a word of a specific line?

Tags: bash, awk, sed

Currently my script looks like this:

```
for subj in 55

do 

cd /path/to/

echo "Total_Volume.txt"

cat Total_Volume.txt

echo "Calculated Volume >> Total_Volume.txt; awk '{total +=$4} END {PRIINT total} Total_Volume.txt

done
```

Since the .txt file initially did not have the word total Volume in it, I used the `echo` command and append to the file first. What I want was to append the total number obtained by the `awk` command (which is 94694) and put it right after the word Total Volume in Total_Volume.txt.

This is how it looks like when I run that part of the script and open .txt:

Total Volume

94694

Anyway that I can write the script so that it shows up like: 
Total Volume 94694

I know that I can use the `sed` command, but I'm not exactly good at it.

Comment: Which output do you want? "Total Volume 94694" or "Calculated Volume 94694"?

Comment: Total Volume 94694. Sorry for the confusion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can print text in `awk` as well, there is no need for code juggling.

I'm guessing this is what you want

```
$ awk '{total += $4} END{print "Total Volume " total}' inputfile > outputfile
```

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you should replace this:

```
echo "Calculated Volume >> Total_Volume.txt; awk '{total +=$4} END {PRIINT total} Total_Volume.txt
```

With:

```
echo "Total Volume `awk '{total +=$4} END {PRIINT total}' Total_Volume.txt `" >> Total_Volume.txt
```